# .NET Core 3.1: pass value from cshtml page input form field to controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, .net-core, razor-pages

I'm looking for a way to pass a value from a Razor page to a controller.

These are my models:

```
public class DocumentModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Titolo")]
    [Required, MinLength(3)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    [Display(Name = "Versione Attiva")]
    public int ActiveVersion { get; set; }
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]

    [Display(Name = "Ultima Versione")]
    public int LastVersion { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DocumentVersionModel> DocumentVersion { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentVersionModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DocumentModelId { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage="Date only")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage="Date only")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime LastChangeDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage="Date only")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DocumentDate { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
    public DocumentModel Document { get; set; }
}
```

This is the form in my Create.cshtml page:

```
<form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Titolo</label>
            <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Data del Documento</label>
            <input asp-for="DocumentVersion.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Version==Model.ActiveVersion).DocumentDate" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="DocumentVersion.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Version==Model.ActiveVersion).DocumentDate" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Versione</label>
            <input asp-for="ActiveVersion" class="form-control" value="1" readonly="readonly"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="ActiveVersion" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Ultima Versione</label>
            <input asp-for="LastVersion" class="form-control" value="1" readonly="readonly"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="LastVersion" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Salva" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
</form>
```

This is the form in my Edit.cshtml page:

```
<form asp-action="Edit">
<div class="row">
    <a class="btn btn-blue-grey" href="/DocumentView">Torna ai documenti</a>
</div>
<br />
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-12 form-group">
        <label>Titolo</label>
        <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" id="iddoc" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Data Documento</label>
            <input asp-for="DocumentVersion.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Version==Model.ActiveVersion).DocumentDate" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="DocumentVersion.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Version==Model.ActiveVersion).DocumentDate" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
//PROBLEM HERE: the DocumentDate value is the today date instead of the chosen date in the input form of the Create.cshtml page
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Data Creazione</label>
            <input asp-for="DocumentVersion.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Version==Model.ActiveVersion).CreationDate" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Data Ultima Modifica</label>
            <input asp-for="DocumentVersion.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Version==Model.ActiveVersion).LastChangeDate" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Ultima versione</label>
            <input asp-for="LastVersion" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Versione attiva</label>
            @Html.DropDownList("ActiveVersion", ViewBag.versionlist as SelectList, new { id = "ActiveVersionSave", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Versione selezionata</label>
            @Html.DropDownList("donotuse", ViewBag.versionlist as SelectList, new { id = "ActiveVersionSelect", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This are the two methods of my controller:

```
// POST: DocumentView/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(DocumentModel documentModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(documentModel);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        var documentId = documentModel.Id;
        return RedirectToAction("edit", new { documentid = documentId });
    }
    return View(documentModel);
}

// GET: DocumentView/Edit/5
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit([FromQuery] int documentid)
{
var wtf = await _context.DocumentModel.Include(e => e.DocumentVersion).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    var documentModel = await _context.DocumentModel.Include(e=>e.DocumentVersion).Where(i=>i.Id==documentid).FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (documentModel.DocumentVersion.Count == 0) 
    {
        documentModel.DocumentVersion.Add(await AddVersion(documentModel, 1).ConfigureAwait(false));
        var versionlist = documentModel.DocumentVersion.ToList();
        ViewBag.versionlist =new SelectList(versionlist,"Version","Version");
    }
    else
    {
        var versionlist = documentModel.DocumentVersion.ToList();
        ViewBag.versionlist =new SelectList(versionlist,"Version","Version");

    }
    return View(documentModel);
}
```

This is the AddVersion function called by the edit: the problem persists here since the DocumentDate is set to DateTime now:

```
private async Task<DocumentVersionModel> AddVersion(DocumentModel doc, int versionnumber)
    {
        var version = new DocumentVersionModel
        {
            DocumentModelId = doc.Id,
            Version = versionnumber,
            CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
            Document = doc,
            DocumentDate = DateTime.Now,
            LastChangeDate = DateTime.Now
        };
        await _context.DocumentVersionModel.AddAsync(version).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return version;
    }
```

I want to save the value of "Data del Documento" to make it appear in the Edit.cshtml page.

NOTE: I'm relatively new to C# and MVC, most of the code written here isn't written by me and was assigned to me by my stage supervisor, so if possible don't just throw some code at me :)

Comment: Why would you let the user enter the document version? Surely that's something the C# code or the database would manage automatically - e.g. setting the version number to 1 when it's created, and increasing it every time the document is edited?

Comment: @ADyson the user can't change the version, the field is read only. The user has two buttons: "Save in this version" and "Save as new version"...

Comment: ok so then maybe I haven't understood the whole scenario, but from what I know so far I'd say the server can set the version appropriately based on what button the user selects (and based on what version already exists for that document, if any). You don't need to upload it (and anyway that just leaves room for someone malicious to alter it and send an inappropriate/invalid value - just because the field is set read-only doesn't mean it can't be altered by someone with a little bit of knowledge).

Comment: @ADyson I didn't receive instruction about the version behaviour so I won't touch it, the main problem here is that I don't know how to pass the Date from a Razor page to a controller ^^

Comment: Sorry maybe I misunderstood? Is the user supposed to be entering a version number on the create page? Is that what you're asking? Because if you have a read-only field in the view, then the only task is to send the value from the controller to the view, not the other way round. You don't need to send it back again because it cannot have changed. If you need to know the current version number again when the form is submitted, then you should find it from the database

Comment: @ADyson the problem is not the version, but the Date. I found a solution anyway and I'll reply to this topic to mark it as a solution ;)

Comment: Ok great sorry I wasn't able to help more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION: I modified the DocumentModel: and added

```
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Date only")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DocumentDate { get; set; }
```

The form in the Create.cshtml is now:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label>Data del Documento</label>
            <input asp-for="DocumentDate" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="DocumentDate" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

And the AddVersion function now is:

```
var version = new DocumentVersionModel
        {
            DocumentModelId = doc.Id,
            Version = versionnumber,
            CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
            Document = doc,
            DocumentDate = doc.DocumentDate,
            LastChangeDate = DateTime.Now
        };
```